# Pytest override fixture with parameterization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, parameterization

The answer to how to override a fixture with parametrization is already given here:
[pytest test parameterization override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919764/pytest-test-parameterization-override)

My question is what is the correct way to run the same test, both with the original fixture and the overridden values.

I'm already using the [pytest-lazy-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/) library to override one fixture with another, but when I run the following pytest:

```py
import pytest
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_value():
    return 0

def test_foo(fixture_value):
    ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_value', (lazy_fixture('fixture_value'), 1, 2, 3))
def test_bar(fixture_value):
    ...
```

I get this error:

`E       recursive dependency involving fixture 'fixture_value' detected`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `fixture_value` name of the fixture is same as the paramter passed to the test.

```
import pytest
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_value():
    return 0



def test_foo(fixture_value):
    assert True

@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixtures_value'[(pytest.lazy_fixture('fixture_value'))]) # Square brackets used here.
def test_bar(fixtures_value): # Note the name here is changed.
    assert True
```

Output:

```
Platform win32 -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
plugins: lazy-fixture-0.6.3
collected 2 items

myso_test.py::test_foo PASSED
myso_test.py::test_bar[fixtures_value0] PASSED
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the fixture name. let me give you a more complicated example, where the 'fixture_value' fixture is used as a value for another fixture, which can't be modified.
Maybe I'm making it way more complicated than it should be, but I'm trying to see if there is a clean solution for this.

Comment: You can keep the original name for fixture. Just change what you pass in parametrize. It can be anything, it doesn't matter.