# pytest user override of parametrized fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a parametrized fixture that my tests are calling with parameters, but I like users / test runner to submit their own parameters, and to override 'default' parameters as coded in with the test.
For non-parametrized fixtures, I override fixture return values via pytest hook

```
def pytest_generate_tests(self, metafunc):
    for fixture_name, parameters in self.fixture_parameters.items():
        if fixture_name in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize(fixture_name, parameters)
```

However for parametrized fixtures, I'm getting "ValueError: duplicate < fixture name > ".
How can I override parametrized fixture?

(there is a similar question, but it poses problem the other way around - pushing precedence for test (code) parameters rather than values submitted via pytest hook pytest_generate_tests() [pytest test parameterization override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919764/pytest-test-parameterization-override) )

Answer (score 0):

the workaround I ended up using is a parameter class

```
    class PARAMCLASS
         forced_param = default value

        @classmethod 
        def force_value(cls, value):
            cls.forced_value = value'''
```

fixture (parametrized by tests themselves via indirect) then looks whether somebody (some runner or pytest plugin or whatnot) set PARAMCLASS.forced_value to anything else than default and if yes acts accordingly, ignoring tests parameters.

This is a horrible solution because PARAMCLASS effectively acts like a global and also it is some shadow test params management outside pytest.